# How to use profileable process in Android Studio Profiler?

Tags: android-studio, android-profiler

I have downloaded a performance-samples project from Github (https://github.com/android/performance-samples/tree/main/JankStatsSample) but do not see a (profileable) process, as shown in below image. Mine is only showing (debuggable). I am using Pixel 5 API 31 with latest version of android (Chipmunk). I have followed the steps on Android Devs website below but still no luck. What am I missing?

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile#profileable-apps

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You've built the debug version of the app, therefore you can profile it without it being profileable. You can simply select the debuggable process if you want to profile it.

Profileable is useful when you want to build a **release** (not debug) version of the app and still profile it (to more accurately check the performance of your app). In case the profileable tag is added to the AndroidManifest.xml, all you need to do is build the release version of the app and it will show as profileable.

[image: Profileable example]

Comment: I have switched the Active Android Studio Build Variant from 'debug' to 'release', followed the Android Devs instructions on https://developer.android.com/studio/profile#build-release-app and rebuilt the project. However it still only shows 'debuggable' in the profiler. how do I profile a release version as you mention?

Comment: If the release version is running, then it should not show up as "debuggable" at all. That might be the previously built debuggable version still running, I'd recommend you to uninstall it first (or force close it). Have you added <profileable android:shell="true"/> to AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: i tried re-installing the app on new AVD but still have the same problem. The manifest file include the `shell=true` line. When you downloaded the the JankStatsSample github project, did it show (profileable) in android studio profiler? Mine did not, trying to narrow down if it's issue with me or the project config

Comment: Are you sure that the profileable tag is present and that you built the release build variant? Because after cloning, I had to manually add it to AndroidManifest and I had to fake sign the app to build the release build. I did successfully run it and I can see the profileable note, see my updated comment for the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks, I have never built a release build and fake signed an app before. I am trying to follow the Android Devs website to do this. If you could share any guides that show the steps you follow that would be greatly appreciated. Also, are you using Android Studio version 2021.2.1?

Comment: I've created keystore file (https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key), generated signed bundle apk (https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign_release), even tried deleting my debug config (just adds back after every build) and also tried changing the debug config to use the release build config but STILL the profiler thinks i'm running debuggable process. What am I doing wrong? Is there special way to launch release apk? Is it cos you are using Pixel 6? Are you able to share step by step what you did to get it to show the 'profileable' process?

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.android.com/studio/run#changing-variant - that's the main way to change which build variant you're building, other than that I just ran the build.

Comment: ok I have updated the Active Build Variant already. looks like Android Studio 2021.1.1 for some reason is still pointing to the debug build every time. One final question sorry, where do you get the Pixel 6 emulator from?

Comment: No worries, did you manage to build the release variant? The Pixel 6 is not an emulator, it's a physical device connected to the PC. Also, if the answer(s) helped, please mark it with the green checkmark as the accepted one. - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Can you try profiling your app on a physical device (any device with API level 29 and newer)? Emulators usually use userdebug builds of a system image, making all processes debuggable. Plus the point of profiling a profileable app is to get accurate timing measurements, however emulators don't reflect the real world performance of a physical device anyway.

Comment: It seems to AVD(emulator) couldn't be a profilable one although the correct set up steps are included but always debuggable.